# Too many libboost_*.lib

Tags: c++, boost

I have downloaded boost 1.58.0 (precompiled, x86, VC 12.0) from http://boost.teeks99.com/ and installed to C:\local\boost_1_58_0 (I also tried compiled the source code using msvc-12.0 by myself and get the same result.

The problem: I see too many libboost*.lib of the same library, for example

`ls -l libboost_math_*` returns:

```
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99f-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99l-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_c99-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1f-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1l-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_math_tr1-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
```

My questions:

1. Why are there so many lib files for one library? (36 files for
   libboost_math, 4 libboost_atomic, 6 libboost_iostreams and so on)
2. Why are there no single libboost_math.lib, libboost_atomic, ...
   files?
3. If I want to use boost_math, which library should I choose?

Comment: Why not instead ask what is the difference between each one? Or, better, find out from the documentation? It'll very quickly become apparent then as to why there is a choice.

Comment: BTW, These are for Visual Studio 2013. VC12 = Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: ***Why are there no single libboost_math.lib, libboost_atomic, ... files?*** That would restrict what configuration and CRT users of the library would be able to compile their application for.

Comment: _which library should I choose?_ boost supports visual c++ auto linking ([#pragma comment(lib,)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx)) so with visual studio you need just include headers and specify libraries directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Math contains many parts, and they don't share the same library file.

The libraries' filename described what it builds for.

For example,

- vc120: it builds for microsoft visual C++ 12.0 (a.k.a. 2013)
- mt: will link with multithread version of C runtime. (libcmt.lib)
- mt-s: will link with multithread version of shared C runtime. (msvcrt.lib)
- mt-gd: will link with multithread debug version of C runtime. (libcmtd.lib)
- mt-sgd: will link with multithread debug version of shared C runtime. (msvcrtd.lib)
- s: will link with singlethread version of shared C runtime. (seems now VC doesn't contains one? I'm not sure.)
- sgd: will link with singlethread debug version of shared C runtime. (seems now VC doesn't contains one? I'm not sure.)

If you are using Boost with Microsoft Visual C++, you will benefit from the auto-link feature. Set the additional library directory and the linker (to be exact, the boost header directs the linker) will link the correct version for you.

Comment: I'm using Node.JS (build with node-gyp) so unfortunately I don't get the benefit of auto-link. Is there anyway to configure binging.gyp to auto link?

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio I'm not familiar with node.js. If it works with msvc compiler, it still benefits from auto-link. If it doesn't use msvc, then the library you downloaded can not be used, and you should download another pre-compiled version or build boost yourself. I recommend build yourself, it's not hard, just cost some time.

Comment: Yep I did build myself (with msvc) and got the same result.
If you build a Visual Studio project (with boost math) using msvc command line, what would you pass in as argument?

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio in fact no special argument should be used except /Id:\boost and at the end of all argument /link /LIBPATH:d:\boost/stage\lib . If you still fail when linking, would you like to try putting these libraries into vc's ibrary directory?

Comment: True, I don't need to specify any libboost_math.lib. My problem comes from an entirely different source. Once that is fixed everything compiles happily.